# Looking for a Simple Proof of the Divergence of the Prime Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> It is well known that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{i}}$$ diverges, where the $p_{i}$'s are the prime numbers.

Does anybody know a very elementary proof of this result that would be suitable for calculus-level students?

Many thanks.

Comment: See Erdős's proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Erd%C5%91s's_proof_by_upper_and_lower_estimates).

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Wonderfully simple ! BTW. At the age of 18 Erdos found a new proof of Bertrand's "Postulate" (first proven in 1837)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very nice proof ([due to Erdös](http://combinatorica.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1938-13.pdf))  that involves a minimum amount of calculus, it is the following:

If $\sum 1/p$ converges then there is an $n$ such that
$$1/p_{n+1}+1/p_{n+2} + \dots < \frac{1}{2}$$
chose one $n$ with this property and consider the set $A$ of all integers composed only by the first $n$ primes: $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$.

let $A(x)$ be the number of elements of $A$ smaller than $x$, now you can write eny element  $a \in A$ as $a=m^2s$ with $s$ squarefree and there are only $2^n$ squarefree integers made by the first $n$ primes. So for all $x$

$$ A(x) \le 2^n\sqrt{x} $$

On the other hand $x-A(x)$ counts the number of integer up to $x$ with at least one prime factor $\ge p_{n+1}$, but this number is at most
$$ \left \lfloor\frac{x}{p_{n+1}} \right \rfloor +
\left \lfloor\frac{x}{p_{n+2}} \right \rfloor + \dots \le \frac{x}{p_{n+1}} +\frac{x}{p_{n+2}} + \dots < \frac{x}2$$
so we get the two inequalities:
$$ A(x) > \frac x2 \quad \text{and} \quad A(x) \le 2^n\sqrt{x} $$
and combining both we get for all $x$:
$$ 2^{n+1} > \sqrt{x} $$
but this is clearly false if $x \ge 2^{2n+2}$ leading to a contradiction, so $\sum 1/p$ diverges.

Comment: +1.... According to Wikipedia (see the link in the comment to the Q by @RobertIsrael) this is due to Erdos but there is no citation or reference.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I hadn't seen the comment, but I have some doubts about my attribution, I had it written in some old notes. I'll try to look later for a reference.

Comment: It's in "Proofs from The Book", which refers to "Uber die Reihe $\sum \frac{1}{p}$", Mathematica, Zutphen B 7 (1938), 1-2.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks, you are right, I have edited the answer. J. Perott has a proof of Euclid's theorem with a similar flavour: If there are only $n$ primes then there are $2^n$ integers not divisible by a square so for any $N$, $$2^n > N-\sum_p N/p^2 > N(1-(\pi^2/6-1)) > N/3$$ and this is false if $N > 3\cdot 2^n$.

Comment: My edit was for typos. In the display following "On the other hand...", the subscripts on the $p$'s were (incorrectly) all $n+1.$

Comment: My 2nd edit was for another typo. In the last displayed line the inequality was the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

Define $\zeta(s) = 1+ \frac{1}{2^s}+ \frac{1}{3^s}+ \frac{1}{4^s}+\cdots ,$ where $s \in \mathbb{R}, s> 1$.

We know that $\zeta(s) = \prod\limits_{p \text{ prime}} \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s} \right)^{-1}.$

Taking $\log$ of both the sides, we have:

$\log \zeta(s) = -\sum\limits_{p \text{ prime}}\log \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s} \right).$

Expanding $\log$ of right-hand side, we have:

$\log \zeta(s) = \sum\limits_{p \text{ prime}} \left( \dfrac{1}{p^s} \right)+ A(s).$

The term $A(s)$ takes into account the higher powers of primes. Moreover $A(s)$ converges at $s=1$

Taking $\ \displaystyle \lim_{s\to 1}$ , the left hand side is infinity and $A(s)$ is finite, so $\sum\limits_{p \text{ prime}} \left( \dfrac{1}{p} \right)$ diverges.

Answer (score 4):

Note:
I improved my answer
to show that

$\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}
\ge \ln(\ln(n))-1
$.

Or Euler's
(off the top of my head):

By unique factorization

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}
&\le \dfrac1{\prod_{p \le n}(1-1/p)}\\
&=\prod_{p \le n}(1+\frac1{p-1})\\
&\le\prod_{p \le n}e^{\frac1{p-1}}
\qquad\text{since } e^x \ge 1+x\\
&=e^{\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p-1}}\\
\text{so}\\
\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p-1}
&\ge \ln(\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k})\\
&\ge \ln(\ln(n))
\qquad\text{by integral test}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\dfrac1{p-1}
\le \dfrac{2}{p}$,
we have
$\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}
\gt \frac12\ln(\ln(x))
$.

Here is an improvement
on this last paragraph.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p-1}
-\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}
&=\sum_{p \le n}(\frac1{p-1}-\frac1{p})\\
&=\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p(p-1)}\\
&\le\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac1{k(k-1)}\\
&\lt 1\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}
\gt \sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p-1}-1
\ge \ln(\ln(n))-1
$.

Comment: We can simplify this somewhat: (1). Each term $1/k$, for $1\le k\le n,$ occurs at least once in the complete expansion of $F(n)=\prod_{p\le n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}p^{-j}. $(Exactly once by unique factorization,but we don't need it).   So $\sum_{k=1}^n(1/k)\le F(n)<\prod_{p\le n}(1-1/p)^{-1}.$  So $\prod_{p\le n}(1-1/p)\to 0.$... So if $p_j$ is the $ j$th prime then $\prod_{j\in \Bbb N}(1-1/p_j)=0.$....A basic result on series is that if $a_j<1$ for all  $j\in \Bbb N$ then $\sum_{j\in \Bbb N} a_j$ converges iff $\prod_{j\in \Bbb N}(1-a_j)>0.$

Comment: A basic "companion" result is that if $a_j\ge 0$ for all $j$ then $\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}a_j<\infty$ iff $\prod_{j\in \Bbb N}(1+a_j)<\infty.$ Both of these basic results can be briefly shown, even without calculus or logarithms (and more easily with'em).

Comment: In my first comment it should say $0\le a_j<1$ instead of $a_j<1.$

Comment: I wanted to get the rate of divergence, not just show that it diverges. I found it interesting that $\sum \frac1{p-1}$ occurred and felt good that I was able (in the addition at the end) to convert this to $\sum \frac1{p}$.

Comment: Interesting that you get such  a good lower bound for $\sum_{p\le n}(1/p)$ by such elementary moves. Using nuclear weapons (i.e. the Prime Number Theorem), the sum is asymptotic (in ratio) to $\ln (\ln n)$.

Comment: Like most of my answers, I did this off the top of me head without looking anything up, so there certainly is a chance I made a mistake. However, I just looked at it again and don't see anything wrong.