# Show that $\ln(\ln(n))$ is not rational for all integers $n\geq2$

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

This occurred to me
while looking at my answer to
[Looking for a Simple Proof of the Divergence of the Prime Harmonic Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302207/looking-for-a-simple-proof-of-the-divergence-of-the-prime-harmonic-series/3302248#3302248)

> Show that
>   $\ln(\ln(n))$
>   is not rational
>   (and is undoubtedly transcendental)
>   for all integers
>   $n \ge 2$.

I am sure that this is true
and have no idea how to prove it.

If it were, then
$n = e^{e^{a/b}}$,
and I don't see
how to manipulate this
to get a contradiction.

Gelfand-Schneider 
doesn't seem to apply.

There may be a theorem that
$e^{e^r}$
is transcendental
for rational $r$,
but I don't know it.

If you can do this,
then do the
$k$-fold
iterated log,
$\ln_k$,
to show that
$\ln_k(n)$
is irrational
(and, again,
undoubtedly transcendental)
for all $n$ large enough
so that
$\ln_k(n)$
is real.

Comment: Have you checked out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063576/is-ln-lnn-irrational-for-any-integer-n1 ? It may or may not be of help.

Comment: Thanks. Essentially the same question. Not surprising.

The answer there shows that it follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture,
which, of course, is not proven.

Comment: One of the reasons why the link `may or may not be of help.'